# Vue.js widget for gimbal control

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, touch, touch-event

I was looking on the web but couldn't find any library for Vue.js that would support a component with the following functionality:
[image: Gimbal control from web app]

Basically it's touch draggable circle and small arrow pointing from the center of the circle to the direction in which you are dragging the finger. It would be used to control hardware gimble from the webapp.

If I go implementing my own version, is there a Vue.js library/extension that would make it easier to implement? I was thinking of just using pure Javascript + CSS and using Vue.js data to hold position state of the circle.